# Can I add multiple arrays within add_theme_support( 'colors' )?

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, add-theme-support

I would like to add all possible options to **add_theme_support( 'colors' )** in WP Customizer.

What I have that worked was:

```
add_theme_support( 'colors' , array(  // Add colors section to Customizer. 
    'slug'      =>  ' content_text_color',
    'default'   =>  '#fff',
    'label'     =>  __('Site Title and Tagline go here')
) ) ;
```

What I have that only gives me the text color is:

```
add_theme_support( 'colors' , array(  // Add colors section to Customizer. 
    'slug'      =>  ' content_text_color',
    'default'   =>  '#fff',
    'label'     =>  __('Site Title and Tagline go here')
), array(
    'slug'      =>  'content_link_color', 
    'default'   =>  '#fff',
    'label'     =>  __('Choose link color')
) ) ;
```

So the second array is not working, or something wrong with how I'm implementing this solution?

Can this be done, what other options can be done in the same "breath" and how would I accomplish this?

Comment: As far as I know this is a closed [set of features](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Customize_Screen#Colors) and `add_theme_support( 'colors'..`  couldn't work even in the  simple version because [there is](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Features#Related) no such feature as 'colors'.

Comment: You'll need to register Customizer sections, controls, and settings here instead as `colors` isn't a core feature which would do those API calls for you.